# Using Nvidia NVDEC and Intel QSV encode

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to combine Nvidia decoder and Intel encoder with FFmpeg?  I've done transcodes with one or the other but not both.
The reason this is desired is because only Intel has an MPEG encoder, Nvidia lacks it, but I'd like to test for performance gains using Nvidia's decoder at the same time.

If this combination is supported, could someone provide a command line example that configures these two hardware accelerations?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if both Intel HD Graphics and NVIDIA GPUs are present, enabled, have propriate drivers, and the FFmpeg version supports it.

The video codecs of the input and the output must be supported by the hardware, and there are other "usual" limitations (like supported pixel format and maximum resolution).

- The decoder (for example `h264_cuvid`) comes before `-i`.
- The encoder (for example `h264_qsv`) comes after the input file name (after `-i`).

Example:

```
ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -vcodec h264_cuvid -i Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_1MB.mp4 -vcodec h264_qsv -pix_fmt nv12 Bunny2.mp4
```

---

FFmpeg log (report):

`ffmpeg version 4.4-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg Stream`
...
`mapping:`
  `Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_cuvid) -> h264 (h264_qsv))`
...